# How to enable -migrations when it gives me an error saying "No context type was found in the assembly 'Project"

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, migration

I'm trying to update my database and for that I nedd to enable-migrations. However, when I enable migrations it gives me the error referenced above. I already tried:

Enable-Migrations -ProjectName MyContextProjectNameHere -StartUpProjectName MyStartUpProjectNameHere -Verbose

[image]

Here is my Data folder:

[image]

But I still have an error. Why is this happening?

Comment: It should be:`Enable-Migrations -ProjectName AppFogos_WebAPI -ContextTypeName ApplicationDbContext -StartUpProjectName StartUpAppFogos_WebApi  -Verbose`.

Comment: If I use this, I get an error saying: The running command stopped because the preference variable "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set to Stop: Project 'StartUpAppFogos_WebApi' is not found

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have replaced `ProjectName` with `AppFogos_WebApi`, but in doing so you also modified the command parameter names. The command should read:

```
Enable-Migrations -ProjectName AppFogos_WebApi -StartUpProjectName AppFogos_WebApi -Verbose
```

Note that this assumes that your model is defined in the same project than your web project.

Comment: I tried this and I get the same error I had before : No context type was found in the assembly 'AppFogos_WebAPI'